# How to refer a project to install package in PyDev

Tags: python, lxml, pydev

I downloaded `lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` from 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, then put it in `D:\My Documents\lxml`. After that I opened the Windows CMD and changed directory to `D:\My Documents\lxml` and then did:

```
>>pip install --index-url http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
unpacking d:\my documents\lxml\lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: lxml
Successfully installed lxml
Cleaning up...
```

How do I now refer to this in an Eclipse/PyDev project?

Edit: (getting closer)

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.5.0 download `lxml-3.5.0.win-amd64-py2.7.exe` (md5)

Run this exe, installing to Python Directory: `C:\Python27\`

Eclipse/PyDev project Python27LibSitePackages now contains `lxml` package and `lxml-3.5.0.py2.7.egg-info`

Create PyDev project from `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` as suggested by @caot below. This project now contains `lxml` package and `lxml-3.5.0.py2.7.egg-info`.

In the project that I want to use `lxml`, I go to Properties > Project References and include the SitePackages project by checking the box.

Still get the error *NameError: global name 'etree' is not defined*

Go to Project Properties > External Libraries > Add source folder
 `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml`

Still get the error *NameError: global name 'etree' is not defined*

Edit 2:
Under `C:\Python27\site-packages`, I do not see `etree.dll`. There is:

```
etree.pyd
lxml.etree_api.h
lxml.etree.h
dtree_defs.h
etreepublic.pxd
```

Edit 3:
The answer seems to be:

- Download .exe (as stated by @caot)
- Be sure that only `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` should be in `PYTHONPATH`, as @Zabio Zadrozny pointed out (via Properites > PyDev-PYTHONPATH > External Libraries > Add source folder)
- Restart Eclipse (as @caot said) a few times until it takes.

Comment: etree.dll (windows) or etree.so(*nix) should be under pathto/lxml/

Comment: Do not see etree.dll (see edit2)

Comment: .pyd: This is basically a windows dll file. etree.pyd for windows. restart eclipse.

Comment: Ok, pyd is the same as dll. Restarting Eclipse has no effect. How do I get the project to recongnize the pyd?

Comment: Do you have pylint installed and activated in Eclipse with Pydev? Pylint erroneously flags lxml as not installed. You can turn off the pylint error with 'disable=no-member' and let Pydev catch any genuine errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux: download lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz, and run: python setup.py install

Windows: install lxml-3.5.0.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> etree.LXML_VERSION
(3, 5, 0, 0)
>>>
```

Comment: The path to Python is *C:\Python27*. I installed the lib in *D:\My Documents\lxml*. Do I need to install it in *C:\Python27* and if so, how do I do this?

Comment: *C:\Python27\\Lib\site-packages* does not contain lxml

Comment: I've copied lxml folder to C:\Python27\\Lib\site-packages. I then did a `pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` in the new lxml folder. I refreshed the new SitePackages project in Eclipse in which an lxml folder now appears, which contains the .whl file. I then include the SitePackages project in the project that I want to use lxml, but it says "No module name lxml" on the statement `import lxml`.

Comment: see edit to question. Getting closer with your suggestion of creating SitePackages project.

Comment: This downloads lxml-3.5.0.tar.gz.asc. Neither I nor Windows knows what to do with an asc file.

Answer (score 1):

Some details:

1. The **PYTHONPATH** entries should only contain the folders which contain the actual packages.

   i.e.: this means that "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lxml" should **NOT** be in the **PYTHONPATH**, only "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" -- which should be there by default.
2. Don't copy anything manually to the site-packages -- doing a pip install should take care of that (if you copied manually, it's possible that you're making things conflict when pip goes on to install it).

So, in short: start with a clean python,  and do a pip install lxml -- pointing to pythonlibs as you did to get the whl (and never copy anything manually to the site-packages) and things should work out without doing anything special.